# HTML character entities and Unicode: how do I write Dvořák in HTML?

Tags: html, unicode, character-encoding

I'm updating the list of music on my orchestra's website. One of the pieces is by [Antonín Dvořák](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton%C3%ADn_Dvo%C5%99%C3%A1k). Normally when faced by symbols or non-English letters (like `£`, `ö`, or `é`) I find an HTML character entity table on the web (like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)) and find the appropriate character entity references' name (e.g. `&pound;`, `&ouml;`, or `&eacute;`).

I have searched through the HTML character entity table; the `á` from Dvořák's surname is there  (it is `&aacute;`), but the `ř` is not. How do I write Dvořák in a web page?

Comment: It occurred to me to check the source of this page itself to see how the stackoverflow engine does it. It has encoded `Dvořák` as `Dvoř&#225;k`, i.e. the `ř` is written in HTML unencoded. That makes me wonder why encode anything?

Comment: Because it is 1996 and your text editor doesn't understand UTF-8? :)

Comment: Quentin - thanks. I think the pages are old and none of the webmasters (now me) have changed the encoding. I'll look at how to do that.

Comment: The other reason is "not knowing how to produce the character on my keyboard". The encoding of the page could be fine.

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0159/index.htm

Comment: Point taken Quentin - I opt for cut-and-paste from Wikipedia when I cannot remember how to produce a symbol (e.g. emdash, the diacritic in my colleague Siân's name, or indeed Dvořák in the question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way as you write it here `Dvořák`.

You only need to use character references if:

- The character has special meaning in HTML: `"`, `'`, `<`, `>`, `&` *or*
- You are using a character encoding which doesn't support the characters you need (but this is 2014, so why would you?)

If you really want to use a character reference, then you can use [a decimal one](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#character-references): `&#xxx;` where `xxx` is [the Unicode codepoint](http://www.unicode.org/charts/).

Comment: Thanks Quentin, the [Cambridge Concert Orchestra](http://www.cambridgeconcertorchestra.org/) home page now has Dvořák's name correctly written with the minimum of fuss on my part and I don't have to search for character entity codes so much in future! Result :-)